# Flexbox: Element shadows doesn't work with order property

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a simple layout using CSS3's flexbox feature but I encountered a problem: I can't put the shadow of my `nav` element over the `main` element even if the `nav` element is after the `main`.

I tried using the `order` property for this but I can't figure out why the `nav`'s shadow is under the `main`

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body >* {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #bdbdbd;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #000;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
main {
  height: 500px;
  order: 1;
}
nav {
  order: 0;
}
footer {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<main>Main content</main>
<nav>Navigation</nav>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cm7L6fht/)

It is possible to do it without using the `poasition:abosolute` property (only with flexbox features)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) property for stacking elements in the desired order.

```
nav {
    order:0;
    z-index:2;
}
```

**Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lfaezsek/1/**

Comment: Cool. But why the z-index works here? It supposed to work only for non static positioned elements..

Comment: @boyd For flex items `z-index` would establish a stacking context even if the computed value of `position` is `static`.

Comment: Very good question, [the w3c says](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting): `Flex items paint exactly the same as inline blocks [CSS21], except that order-modified document order is used in place of raw document order, and z-index values other than auto create a stacking context even if position is static.`

Comment: I did not know it before either, glad you asked. Best of luck!