# Does z-index specify the stack level of a non-positioned flex item?

Tags: css, flexbox, z-index, language-lawyer

In CSS 2.1, [`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index) only applies to positioned elements, and specifies two different things:

> 1. The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
> 2. Whether the box establishes a stacking context.

But [Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting) says this:

> [Flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item) paint exactly the same as inline blocks [[CSS21]](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#biblio-css21),
>   except that [`order`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-order)-modified document order is used in place of
>   raw document order, and [`z-index`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-position-3/#propdef-z-index) values other than `auto` create a
>   stacking context even if [`position`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-position-3/#propdef-position) is `static`.

Then, unlike CSS2.1, setting `z-index` to some integer on a non-positioned flex item creates a stacking context.

However, I don't see defined anywhere which should be the stack level of this stacking context.

A similar case is [`opacity`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency), which can also create establish stacking contexts on non-positioned elements. But in this case the stack level is properly specified to be 0:

> If an element with opacity less than 1 is not positioned,
>   implementations must paint the layer it creates, within its parent
>   stacking context, at the same stacking order that would be used if it
>   were a positioned element with `z-index: 0` and `opacity: 1`.

In my opinion these options are reasonable:

- The stack level is the value specified in `z-index`
- The stack level is 0
- The flex item wraps its descendants in a stacking context so that they are painted together, but the flex item itself is painted as a normal in-flow non-positioned elements (as if it didn't establish an stacking context).

According to the following test, both Firefox and Chrome do the first option.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.item {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ffa;
  align-self: flex-start;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.item:nth-child(even) {
  background: #aff;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.za::after{ content: 'z-index: auto'; }
.z0 { z-index: 0; } .z0::after{ content: 'z-index: 0'; }
.z1 { z-index: 1; } .z1::after{ content: 'z-index: 1'; }
.z-1 { z-index: -1; } .z-1::after{ content: 'z-index: -1'; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item z1"></div>
  <div class="item z0"></div>
  <div class="item za"></div>
  <div class="item za"></div>
  <div class="item z-1"></div>
</div>
```

Is this behavior defined somewhere?

Comment: An intriguing question raised by your question and, in particular, your snippet is: *How is `z-index` working without the `order` property?* The spec clearly says the document order has to be *`order`-modified*, but you were able to control the layering of your divs without `order` anywhere in the code.

Comment: @Michael_B That's not the way I read the spec...it's just detailing the differences...not saying that `order` is required to establish `z-index`.

Comment: @Paulie_D, then I must have made a mistake [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33391370/3597276), because I couldn't get `z-index` to work without the `order` property.

Comment: Perhaps so...clearly it is possible from Oriol's demo. I've checked the spec and I can only find the single reference to z-index as mentioned above. I guess the default stack level isn't defined just that a stack is created.

Comment: @Michael_B In my understanding, the sentence in the spec means that boxes with the same stack level are painted back-to-front according to `order` (outside flexbox it would be document tree order).

Comment: When I answered [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33391370/3597276) 2 months ago I spent about 30 minutes trying to figure out why `z-index` wasn't working on the flex items. It wasn't until I tried `order` (with a helpful nudge [from this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27484191/3597276)), that everything fell in place. Up until that point, the spec language itself wasn't entirely clear to me.

Comment: @Michael_B In fact I saw your answer and thought that `order` seemed unnecessary in case `z-index` determined the stack level in non-positioned flex items, but otherwise either `order` or positioning were necessary. So I asked this question to know which should be the case. Thanks for making me think about this part of the spec.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Thanks, I wanted to start a bounty myself but forgot. Hopefully it will attract Xanthir, dholbert or someone with great knowledge about flexbox.

Comment: I don't see why CSS2.1 would not apply here. At the very least, that's what Firefox and Chrome seem to be doing. (I can't comment on how the `order` property affects this.)

Comment: @BoltClock The problem is that CSS2.1 says that `z-index` does not apply to non-positioned elements. And [Elaborate description of Stacking Contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html) does not consider non-positioned stacking context.

Comment: @Oriol: Oh, right, I forgot.

Comment: @Oriol, not sure 50 rep points will bring any big names out of hiding ;-) You may just want to ping them directly.

Comment: @Michael_B Starting a bounty worked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31094454/1529630), though :) And [pinging directly is not appreciated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309690/1529630).

Comment: @Oriol, not to make this a big deal, but the bounty example could have been luck, or even a question he would have answered regardless of bounty. The second point, about *not appreciated*, is highly subjective. Some people may not appreciate a special request for an answer. Others may be flattered by the request, and happy to oblige. Trust me, if ever I need an answer to a difficult question, you can expect a ping from me ;-) You can always just ignore it.

Comment: @Michael_B Hopefully the bounty will attract somebody who can answer, even if it's not somebody involved in the spec (that would require lots of luck, yes). I don't mind being pinged if the question is interesting

Comment: @Oriol I remember tweeting Tab directly asking if he could answer that question, sorry to rain on your bounty theory :-) but that was sort of a unique case that kind of *required* a WG member to answer. This one may actually a similar case, though...

Comment: @TylerH Good to know XD thanks

Comment: @Oriol [Tweet in question](https://twitter.com/Tyler_Hibbard/status/615969917179928577)

Comment: Seems like a few tweets might be what we need @Michael_B :)

Answer (score 6):

CSS Working Group:

> The CSSWG couldn't think of a good reason to make flex items establish
>   pseudo-stacking contexts, so we have resolved to treat them the same
>   way as block and table cell elements.
>
> <sub>source: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Jul/0382.html</sub>

More information:

- [[css3-flexbox] Painting order](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Jul/0469.html)
- [[css3-flexbox] Paint flex items atomically?](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Jul/0237.html)
- [[css3-positioning] z-index and pseudo-stacking contexts](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Jul/0546.html)
- [[css3-flexbox][css-ALL] Should z-index Just Work on flex items?](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Jul/0190.html)

---

Also, although not a direct answer to the question, the following **W3C Editor's Drafts** provide strong hints as to where CSS is going with `z-index` and stacking contexts.

[**11. Layered presentation**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#layered-presentation) ~ [CSS Positioned Layout Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/)

[**12. Detailed stacking context**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/#det-stacking-context) ~ [CSS Positioned Layout Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/)

[**4.3. Z-axis Ordering: the `z-index` property**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#z-order) ~ [CSS Grid Layout Module Level 1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/)

It's interesting to note that `z-index`, as currently defined in the [CSS Positioned 3 Editor's Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#layered-presentation), applies only to positioned elements. This is no different than [CSS 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index). Yet [grid items](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#z-order) and [flex items](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#painting) can both create stacking contexts with `z-index`, even when `position` is `static`.

Comment: The [first version of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/#painting) that mentions z-index and stacking on the vertical plane appears to be newer than those Working Group conversations. That could be strong evidence that they changed their mind; as I understand it, these drafts (in any state) take precedence over mailing list conversations.

Comment: There is good info in those threads, thanks. I will read them thoroughly tomorrow. The concept of pseudo stacking context seems useful, I wonder why they didn't use it in CSS2.1 nor CSS3-Positioning

Comment: The quote from [CSS Grids](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#z-order) is interesting: "*values other than auto create a stacking context even if position is static. **Thus** the z-index property can easily be used to control the z-axis order of grid items.*". The "thus" seems to mean that the second sentence is only a clarification, and z-index can always (not only in grids) control the z-axis order of stacking contexts, even if CSS Positioned doesn't seem to say this. Then it would apply to non-positioned flex items with z-index.